# Can I add tracking history to a field using apex?

Tags: apex, history-tracking, package-install

I wrote an integration app that imports contacts from an external system.

If the contacts already exists (ie. same name, or same email, or user selected) the data of the contact in salesforce is overwritten with the data of the contact in the ext system.

Therefore I would like to be sure that Field history tracking is enabled on those fields (Contact.FirstName,LastName,Email) and if not, enable it.

I saw here [Field History : how to detect in apex which fields are tracked?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/91646/field-history-how-to-detect-in-apex-which-fields-are-tracked) that I can check wether the field is tracked or not, but as we could suppose :

```
Field is not writeable: FieldDefinition.IsFieldHistoryTracked
```

Is there any way to enable it programmatically ?

I saw that the Contact.object file changed when I manually activated the history on email field from

```
<enableHistory>false</enableHistory>
...
<fields>
    <fullName>Email</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
</fields>
```

to

```
<enableHistory>true</enableHistory>
...
<fields>
    <fullName>Email</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <trackHistory>true</trackHistory>
</fields>
```

So I guess deploying this file might be a way (even if I don't really know how), but how to do that in a package installation ?

Comment: You could try deploying updated metadata through the metadata api. An easy way to upload metadata is through [workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/).

Comment: Thanks but I need it to be set in a package. When people (that I don't know in advance) will install the package, the first thing they'll do is import data, so I need the field history to be set up before, so they don't accidentally lose data

Comment: Can I download , edit, and upload again object metadata in a VF page, using ajax and metadata API ?

Comment: Looks like you're in luck, a metadata api for apex was released in summer '17 [Source](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2017/05/introducing-apex-metadata-api.html) ... or not, seeing as it only provides two types of metadata.. yikes.

Comment: Looks like you'd need to use [the metadata api wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi), which requires some setup, and basically calls out to the webservice metadata api from apex.

Comment: Try modifying a .object file, and deploying it through workbench. If this works, and enables field tracking, then setup the metadata api and write some code to callout when appropriate.

Comment: It works with Mavensmate/SublimeText so it would in workbench, but do It looks complicated since I would have to authenticate in some way to use this API. I don't want to ask customer authentication since he is already in Salesforce. I'm afraid I'll have to wait for the apex metadata api to be more complete... In the meantime, if tracking is not enabled I can ask the customer to enable it, and if he doesn't, handle a homemade tracking with notes...

Comment: I'm with battery.cord here - you should be able to use the [Apex Metadata API wrapper](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) as it will use the sessionId of the running user (presumably the package installer, a sysad)